# Getting TypeError Arg 1 when calling save method of jsPDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

I have a very simple implementation of jsPDF in a react project I'm currently working on. Just trying to run the sample 'hello world' code but the save method throws the following error:

[image]

My code is very simple, first, import the lib like this:

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

Then on a click event function from a Component

```
<IOControls exportDrawing={this.exportDrawing} />
```

I run:

```
exportDrawing() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text('Hello World!', 10, 10);
    console.log(doc); // shows an object
    doc.save('a4.pdf');
}
```

The above error triggers on **save()** but I have no idea what exactly is causing it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I just noticed that if I call the methods at the root of my app component the code works fine, the problem ocurrs when it is called from within other components.

Here is my setup

```
<App>
  <Sketch>
    <SketchControls>
    <IOControls>
```

`exportDrawing()` is declared in `<Sketch>` and the its triggered from a button in `<IOControls>`

Comment: After spending sometime looking searching for this kind of error, it looks like it may be an incompatibility with my webpack setup, but I create a project from scratch with my template and it works just find. I compare the package.json, webpack.config and babel settings and they are all the same... I dont know where else to look.

Comment: can you reproduce this error somewhere? (jsfiddle or codepen) . That would help others solve your problem easily

Comment: I know, unfortunately I can't reproduce the error in CodeSandbox as a simple bare-        bones app with the Components setup I previously mention in my update works :'(

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce.
I created the sandbox. But it works fine.
Just Have a look at - > https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-sammet-voijh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there was a method form another library causing a scope issue.

I'm using the [paperjs](http://paperjs.org/) library as my drawing engine. I called the [paper.install(window)](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/) method that gives scope to the window DOM element. By removing this call **jspdf** works.